# How to catch the exit() event in PHP?

Tags: php, events

When `exit()` is executed,trigger another procedure,is there an easy way?

Answer (score 9):

`exit()` terminates the execution of the script -- so, there is not much than can be done after it's been called.

Still, quoting the manual :

> [Shutdown functions](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) and [object
>   destructors](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.destructor) will always be
>   executed even if `exit()` is called.

So, you cannot "*trigger another procedure*" when `exit()` is called -- but you can register a function that will be called each time the PHP script ends ; including the times when it's being terminated because of a call to `exit()`.

Comment: I found `lime_test` can do this,but don't know they approaches it.

Comment: I suppose it's using a shutdown function *(or some object destructor)* ;-)

Answer (score 6):

When exit is called, you'll still trigger any registered [shutdown functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php).  You can use that to "catch" any calls to exit.

Answer (score -2):

Try looking at [runkit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php), maybe it will help you.